# Invoke startService()/bindService() from Service to Service?

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to run `startService()` or `bindService()` from a `Service` to another `Service`s?

Answer (score 0):

`startService()` can be used even if you call this method inside a `Service`. So, it's possible to trigger another `Service` from the current `Service`. But you can't call `bindService()` to trigger another `Service`, it requires an activity to be bound and display the result in UI, such as MP3 Player. Once an activity which calls `bindService()` was destroyed, the bound-service will be killed by system.